# Save data on iOS device permenatly

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, udid

I want to save data on device itself that would be persistent even after deleting the app and installing it again (data can even be one int/date). 
According to my knowledge it is impossible because each app can store data only on it's sandbox (I know I can use iCloud etc. but I don't want any services user can not have or give the app specific permissions).

As to my understanding the only option to do that is to store it on my server.
But, Apple doesn't allow to send UDID or any other specific device ID and I can't get the iTunes ID. I know I can use any other ID like Facebook ID but the app doesn't have it and that would make a really bad user experience.

I've download apps that does just that successfully (saving data specifically to my device that been recovered even after deletion and without the need to enter any ID or login process). How do they do it? Do they send UDID to some server and apple miss that or there is a way to save data outside the app sandbox?

Comment: Did the app you are talking about were using GameCenter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is the KeyChain, which can store data the would kept even if you delete the app.

Comment: Thanks!
I've used UICKeyChainStore, Very recommended!

Comment: Does Keychain means it should only save some things related with `Key` `Token` `Auth`?

Comment: The Keychain is meanly used for store credentials (keys,tokens, authentication, ...) But in theory you can save any kind of data to the keychain. But it was not designed with this in mind.

Answer (score 4):

We do that too in our app:

Basiclly we create an UDID of our own and store that on the device (in the keychain).
Combined with user id that gives us all we need on the server side to identify the user and his device. We don't store any other app data on the device, all is server managed.

Answer (score 0):

You could pack your data up, store it in the documents folder for your app, and back up your device to the cloud or iTunes. you can then do a restore to get it back.  You just can't do anything on your phone between the backup and the restore.  Just saying.